# Долго загружается сайт.

Tags: mysql, веб-сервер, производительность

Вообщем у меня есть сайт montytool.ru, для которого насоздавали множество программ, которые автоматически выполняют задания. До них всё было хорошо, сайт летал, как появились программы, создающие тысячи запросов в секунду, начались сильные лаги.

Пользовался командой **SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST** для просмотра sql запросов:

Пытался что-то оптимизировать, но против огромного потока это не прошло. Индексы, всё это есть. Как не было программ для сайта, всё летало с бешенной скоростью. Уже и ввёл лимиты на частые запросы, но ничего не помогает, сайт грузит очень долго, забивает CPU.

Стоит на сервере, freebsd.

Посоветуйте что-то, как бороться с этим. Неужели мне надо тратить миллионы на сервер.. Или же можно что-то придумать? :(

[image]

[image]

Comment: "насоздавали множество программ, которые автоматически выполняют задания". Может стоит попробовать поискать корень бед в них?

Comment: @Sasha121, прикрывать смысла нет. Новое придумают.

Comment: @Modal, судя по обсуждению здесь и [другому Вашему вопросу](http://hashcode.ru/questions/189092/%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B1-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0) здесь идет речь об *виртуальной машине?*

В принципе я ничего не имею против виртуалок, но только если они свои (на своем железе), а не арендуемые неизвестно у кого.

Возьмите выделенный сервер, как советовал @Shrek, и тогда можно будет предметно обсуждать производительность.

Comment: По вашим скриншотам - нагрузка по процу уже великовата. Можно расширять.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

А тысячи, это сколько?

Нагрузка по процессору 100%?

Запрос к вашему сайту только что прошел через nginx с третьего раза, до этого было две 502 ... То есть грустно довольно ((

Чего можно пробовать...
Перво-наперво **анализ природы и характера нагрузки**. А с какого они полезли делать по 1000 запросов, можно ли 1000 простых запросов заменить 5 запросами с join? 
Я вообще плохо представляю, какая задача может потребовать 1000 запросов.

Можно ли перестроить что-то в АРІ, чтоб не они делали 1000 запросов (например, сверяя, не изменилось ли что-то), а чтоб делали 1, в котором ваш сервер отдавал готовую инфу, что именно изменилось.

Судя по снимку экрана идет куча запросов вида key-value, можно ли поднять memcache/tmpfs, (или nosql БД, но не факт сразу) и юзеров отдавать оттуда.

Далее. Классика высоконагруженных систем. Вы должны понять, каково у вас соотношение запросов на чтение данных и запросов на их модификацию. В классике это соотношение 10к1, но в веб решениях мне случалось видеть и 200к1 (а в соцсетях и того больше).

Начиная с соотношения где-то 50к1 уже имеет смысл перестраивать алгоритмы и принципы хранения данных так, чтоб основные операции выполнялись один раз при записи, а не много раз при чтении.

Пример. Большой новостной ресурс. При добавлении новости, она:

1. Пишется в БД.
2. Перегенерируется страницы данного блока новостей, и все дерево, где данная новость есть. Перегенерируются статические вставки на главную. Перегенерируется RSS-лента.
3. Создается сама страница новости.
4. Пинается nginx

Процедура ЗАПИСИ новости занимает примерно 1.26 секунды, на все про все (в общей сложности пересоздается около 20 файликов). А отдача - все на что способен nginx без обращения к НТТР серверу. Если nginx убрать, скорость отдачи падает в разы, на даже апач в таком режиме дает 7-10К страниц.

У вас задача другая, но принцип - медленно писать быстро читать спасал многих)

Удачи!

Comment: @SilverIce, 100% да. Они пишут тяп ляп, главное работало, а потом продают и наживаются. Им всё равно на запросы и что как там, главное же работает, как считают они. А вообще сервер мощный по идее будет быстро обрабатывать?

Comment: Замеры по времени (которые в тексте) делались на машинке типа [T2250](http://ark.intel.com/products/27232/Intel-Core-Duo-Processor-T2250-2M-Cache-1_73-GHz-533-MHz-FSB) лет так 5 назад))) то ли Т2700....

Вы понимаете, что если вы туда всунете хотя бы i5 жизнь будет гораздо лучше.

Пробуйте понимать, для каких целей они делают 100 запросов (и мля ж наверно 100 пинков сервера по НТТР). Пробуйте заменить из одним. И кеширование-кеширование-кеширование.

Comment: @SilverIce, быдлокодеры, вот кто они. Ответьте, пожалуйста на вопрос: >> вообще сервер мощный по идее будет быстро обрабатывать? и желательно посмотреть http://hashcode.ru/questions/189092/%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B1-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C-%D1%81-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0 :)

Comment: Толкаете на цугундер))

Как можно не видя системы предполагать хватит вам на нее ресурсов или нет)?

Нужно понимать, сколько ресурсов потребляется сейчас. И брать... ну хотя бы столько же... А по мере надобности - наращивать, благо VDS, это позволяет.

По ссылке:

- Немного смущает убунта, в качестве серверной ОС, но это наверно дело вкуса.
- Сильно смущает канал в 1 мегабит... Как на нагруженный сервер может быть маловато...

Comment: @SilverIce, как это посмотреть? Я такой нуб. Система FreeBSD. Какие команды для консоли? ><

Comment: 1. http://yurasik.org.ua/monitoring-freebsd-sredstva-monitoringa/ - полезный список всяких комманд.

2. Мне хватало http://rtfm.co.ua/freebsd-iftop-monitoring-zagruzki-kanala/, но возможно вам подойдет что-то типа - http://nagios.org/ или http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zabbix. Лучше перед тем как ставить посоветоваться с тем, кто первоначально настраивал сервер, ну или как минимум предупредить. Вероятность, что в ядре где-то что-то патчилось так, что установкой этого вы запорите систему ну практически равна нулю, но лучше подстраховаться.

Comment: 3. Статистику по сети может быть может дать хостер, у кого вы размещаете сервер.

4. На сервере может стоять какая-то панель администрирования. У них обычно есть хотя бы какие-то средства мониторинга.

Comment: @SilverIce, посмотрите, пожалуйста парочку скринов, зашёл в панель администрирования и посмотрел. http://clip2net.com/clip/m40641/1359801116-clip-17kb.png http://clip2net.com/clip/m40641/1359801159-clip-16kb.png http://clip2net.com/clip/m40641/1359801191-clip-15kb.png

Answer (score 2):

Иногда не все запросы тормозят сайт, а какой-то один +не факт еще что именно запрос, может просто участок кода тормозить, напр. который массив обрабатывает какой-то.

Comment: @Maris, нет походу... Так как уже и пустую страницу создашь, без всяких запросов и она долго грузится. Очень трудно попасть на сайт становится. Не может же php код творить такое...

Comment: может, кэш почистить пробовали?

Comment: @Maris, не будут же его чистить все...

Comment: а вы *всеми пробовали, или только на вашем оборудовании и ПО такое?

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте сделать индексными поля по которым идёт выборка, например, id в notifications, выборку из таблицы users делать не по условию where `hash`= 'some_hach' а по id этого пользователя (для поля id тоже сделать индекс), ну это как минимум из того что на скриншоте.

Comment: @Зоркий, пробывал, не помогает никак...

Comment: Я посмотрел ваш сайт, а также хостинг вашего проекта. Вобщем первое что пришло в голову, вам нужно не сайт оптимизировать, а купить нормальную хостинговую площадку (сайт вашего хостера не вызывает никакого доверия и так скорее всего дикий оверселл). Я более чем уверен что проблема исчезнет. Попробуйте облачный scale server, он стоит копейки, можности можно добавлять по мере их необходимости, стоит буквально 5-9 рублей в месяц (на примере проекта с 500 униками и тяжелым социально-блоговом движком).

Answer (score 2):

Нужна более подробная статистика: поставьте [munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/), если ещё не, чтобы видеть загрузку CPU, диска и статистику запросов к MySQL хотя бы. Станет понятно, что можно оптимизировать.

Если много SELECT'ов, можно поднять ещё один сервер с MySQL Slave'ом, чтобы из него только читали все эти приложения.

Однотипные чтения по ключу — [@Silverice](/users/2993/silverice) уже написал про Memcached.